# multiple ldap connections on adldap2-laravel with login_fallback and auto_connect

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

I'm using adldap2-laravel with multiple connections to different ldap servers, I love also the login_fallback feature.

The problem is that auto_connect=true throws exception when one ldap server is down, making the login_fallback useless.

From the docs:

> To swap connections on the fly, set your configurations default
>   connection and try re-authenticating the user:
>
> $auth = false;
>
> if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
>       $auth = true; // Logged in successfully } else {
>       // Login failed, swap and try other connection.
>       Config::set('adldap_auth.connection', 'other-connection');
>
> ```
> if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
>     $auth = true; // Passed logging in with other connection.
> } }
> ```
>
> if ($auth === true) {
>       return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles); }
>
> return 'Login incorrect!';

I would like to use multiple connections, with login_fallback feature enabled and feature auto_connect disabled, but I cannot figure out how to connect to the second ldap (ldap bind) before the connection swap.